# Is there any way to reload failed tile source images in bing V8?

Tags: bing-maps, bing

I was creating an animated tile layer using bingv8.Animations work perfectly fine but there are some broken images in layer which failed to load during the first load.Problem is that it bing naimations loop through this array of images and won't reload failed ones.Is there any way i can reload this broken tile images.

Picture Below

[image: Bing ISSUE]

Code

```
   var displayradMessages = [];
    var radtileSources = [];

    //Create a tile source for each time stamp.
    for (var i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
    var iterDate = forecastDates[i];
    var ts = iterDate.toISOString().substring(0, 19);
    var isPast = iterDate.getTime()<now.getTime();
    var layerName = futureLayerName;

        var radtileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({
            uriConstructor: 'http:example.com/smt/'+ApiKey+'/'+layerName+'/' + ts + '/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png'
        });
        radtileSources.push(radtileSource);
         var radmsg = updateFrameCounter(i);
         displayradMessages.push(radmsg);
    }
    //Create the animated tile layer and add it to the map.
    animatedTileLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.AnimatedTileLayer({
        mercator: radtileSources,
        frameRate: 2000
    });

   //Add an event handler that fires for each frame of the animation
   Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(animatedTileLayer, 'onFrameLoaded', function (e) {
        var radmsg = displayradMessages[e.index];
           var opacity = currentOpacity;
        document.getElementById('satframeTimeStamp').value = radmsg;
       if (animatedTileLayer._htmlElement && animatedTileLayer._htmlElement.style.opacity !== opacity) {
    animatedTileLayer._htmlElement.style.opacity = opacity;
}
    });
    map.layers.insert(animatedTileLayer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any option to reload individual tiles. You can try zooming in/then out to see if that helps. If not, you likely will need to remove the tile layer then re-add it.